# How can I scramble a text file table, with a table

Tags: shell, text, table

I have a table. The column order must not be changed. And the values should be kept.

```
Name    Age size    Code
Abel    10  S   A
Bjorn   20  M   B
Casimir 30  L   C
Dennis  40  XL  D
```

I don't just want to shuffle the lines, but all values independently.
So as example output:

```
Name    Age size    Code
Casimir 20  M   D
Dennis  10  L   C
Bjorn   40  XL  A
Abel    30  S   B
```

So shuf does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `bash` and GNU `shuf` to create a randomised version of the data.  The script assumes that the input file pathname is given on the command line and will output the result on standard output.  The input is assumed to be tab-delimited.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

cols=$( awk -F '\t' '{ print NF; exit }' <$file )

result=$(mktemp)
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

trap 'rm -f "$result" "$tmpfile"' EXIT

for ((i = 1; i <= cols; ++i)); do
    cut -f "$i" <"$file" |
    { IFS= read -r header; printf '%s\n' "$header"; shuf; } |
    paste "$result" - >$tmpfile

    mv "$tmpfile" "$result"
done
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]//' <$result
```

The script starts by calculating the number of columns in the input data.  It does this by simply asking `awk` for the number of tab-delimited fields on the first line of input.

The script then goes through the tab-delimited columns of the input file, one by one, and for each column it reads the header and shuffles the other rows.  The header and the shuffled rows are then added to a temporary output file.

At the end, because the output now contains a tab at the start of each line, it is filtered through `sed` to remove these.

Example runs:

```
$ ./script.sh file
Name    Age     size    Code
Dennis  20      L       B
Bjorn   30      S       C
Abel    40      XL      A
Casimir 10      M       D
```

```
$ ./script.sh file
Name    Age     size    Code
Bjorn   40      S       D
Abel    30      XL      C
Casimir 10      M       A
Dennis  20      L       B
```

Comment: I would have done that in a similar way. But not with your elegance and features.